# Old ERC-20 TRX Tokens Swap Issue

Tags: erc-20, swaps, tron

I tried the instructions given [here](https://medium.com/@tronix_official/how-to-migrate-erc-20-tron-to-trx-20-mainnet-tron-updated-14666b511efa) to swap my old (pre-2018 swap) TRX tokens based on the Ethereum network to the MainNet ones. I sent the tokens to the smart contract address mentioned in the article (**0xf98d419274d678225df329bcb0a703964f5b1acb**) and observed that they were retransferred to an address etherscan labels as "Binance 14". The article states that you are supposed to automatically receive an equivalent amount in MainNet TRX, but this has not happened. I have reached out to Binance regarding this. They were actually welcoming and tried to help me with the matter, but told me that I need to follow up the matter with Tron DAO themselves. I've been trying to get in touch with someone from Tron, and have tried virtually any platform there is to reach them to no avail. At least yet!

Has Anyone tried with success the instructions mentioned in the article?

I wanted to provide more details, but feel that it might violate some rule here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to get this resolved? I'm in exactly the same position right now. I followed the instructions in that same article but 3 weeks later and I still haven't received my mainnet tokens. Im really hoping it's not a scam but it's not looking good so far. I've reached out to every Tron contact I can find. Twitter, instagram, discord, email ...but I get zero response from any of them. Nice way to treat an early investor of their project right? A member of the Tron team could at least confirm whether that is an official article or not. Even the subreddit mod who posted a link to the artic

Comment: I'm afraid that's bad news! The smart contract seems very likely (almost surely) a scam. I did follow the matter up with some good folks at Binance Support (the smart contract transfers the coins to a known Binance ETH address), and they acknowledged the transfer of the tokens to their address, but directed me to get law enforcement involved for any further investigation, as their protocols prevented them to share any further info. I did contact the police, filed a report, and am waiting. Realistically, I am hopeless and have forgotten about the whole thing. I hope your case goes differently.

Comment: Man, I was hoping you wouldn't say that.   Bye bye $800.   That's an expensive lesson in due diligence for me.   It was posted by a mod in a subreddit and most of the "other" commenters "seemed" to receive their tokens tho one person claimed it took him 3 months to receive it.  I let my guard down...won't happen again.   It's still a very bad look that NO ONE from Tron would take a second to reply to a very early investor - I hope the project tanks in spectacular fashion lol

Comment: The amount I lost was unfortunately even more! The thing that struck me the most was how non-responsive TRON people were. I reached out to them in so many different social media, but absolutely no response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear about your situation. I would recommend persisting in your attempts to reach out to TRON's official support. Additionally, you might find it beneficial to post your issue on TRON's community forums or social media platforms, where other users might have experienced a similar situation and could provide guidance.

https://tron.live/

Search "trondao" on Discord

https://tron.network/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am actually trying to maximize my chances by posting about the issue on different but official platforms that I can find. Will post any updates here for future reference.